# Who decides Char[] size in defination of Characters() of saxParser

Tags: java, saxparser

I am facing issue regarding parsing Large Xml file through SAXParser that's why
I want to know how the  size of ch[] array is decided for bellow mentioned
Characters()  method

```
 public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length){
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what your original issue is to get better answers. In general, it's up to the `Parser` or `XMLReader` object to decide on the length of that array.

Comment: The parser does, of course, on any basis it likes. You don't need to worry about it. All you have to do is accumulate the chars until `endElement()` is called.